# JVM : Bytecode Confusion and JIT

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm

So here's a question that came to my mind when I was studying Java. We know (please correct me if I am wrong!) that the Bytecode runs atop JVM. So does the JVM convert the Bytecode to the native machine code it's(JVM) written for? If that is so, isn't it less secure?

Also what exactly is a just-in-time compiler? It compiles when it is asked to do so...I studied some resources, but still didn't get the just-in-time part clear.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: 1) Less secure than what?  2) The "code" (it's not "bytecode") in a Java .class file MAY be converted to machine instructions, or it may be directly interpreted.  3) The conversion to machine instructions, if done, is usually done by a "just-in-time compiler" (JITC), operating silently within the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So does the JVM convert the Bytecode to the native machine code
>   it's(JVM) written for?

No, not necessarily. Though, nowadays it is state of the art to do so by default.

> If that is so, isn't it less secure?

Less secure than what?
Just because one can do insecure operations in machine code (like dereferencing an unitialized pointer or accessing unallocated memory) does not mean the JIT generates such insecure code.

> Also what exactly is a just-in-time compiler?

It's that part of the JVM that converts bytecode to native machine code.
The name "just in time" means that the code is compiled (in a separate thread) while it is executed. Once completely compiled, the JVM takes notice that certain methods are compiled and can be invoked on the machine level.

Comment: Why is it called Just-in-time. And less secure that say the way JavaScript runs ! I mean as they say security (although not now a days) has been Java's forte, for the virtualization the code runs through. But if finally the code is converted to Machine Code, it's so same as C or C++ just that I need not compile it to a native M/C code, the fine guys at Oracle write a JVM for me. Is not that so?

Comment: It's not "so same as C or C++". Remember, JVM isn't only JIT. In fact there're some JVMs on the market which allow to do Ahead-Of-Time compilation - fully converting byte-code to native code at compile-time (from Java sources) as opposed to compilation in run-time with JIT. With this AOT approach JVM still should be loaded and running at program run-time for memory management and Garbage Collection, for example.

Answer (score 0):

> So does the JVM convert the Byte-code to the native machine code it's(JVM) written for?

All JVM implementation I have seen so far are converting byte-code to the native machine code VM is written for. Although I can't see how and why doing otherwise would be useful.

> Also what exactly is a just-in-time compiler?

It's simply process of converting byte code to native code in run-time. Although for performance improvement it's being done by VM in parallel with your program execution. It also usually including compiled native code caching and some other techniques of performance improvement.

> If that is so, isn't it less secure?

Well, to some very small degree it is. VERY VERY SMALL DEGREE. There're some security-related modifications to different OSes eliminating JIT compilation. For example, grsecurity Linux kernel patch is in fact doing JIT impossible (actually doing impossible to execute JIT-compiled code). And another fact is that similar memory protection mechanism (writable memory pages can't be executable) is implemented in iOS which makes impossible to do any JIT compilation in user mode.